# GitHub Actions- separation of permissions

Tags: github-actions

I use GitHub Actions for deployment resources in Azure.
I would like each resource to be created using a different account.

1. access to storage with tfstate in subscription 1 – spn-tfstate
2. deployment storage account in subscription 2 – spn-sa
3. deployment sql db in subscription 3 – spn-sql

how to do it ? separate workflows ? but the same workflows must use at least two accounts for tfstate and resource deployment. Can workflow use two other accounts at the same time?

Can someone tell me how to use several accounts in one workflow to create terraform?

now I have it, but it doesn't work. always uses one account

```
name: 'Terraform Init & Apply'

on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  terraforminitapply:
    name: 'Terraform init & apply'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    #environment: production
    env:
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.BACKEND_CLIENT_ID }}
      ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.BACKEND_TENANT_ID }}
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.BACKEND_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup Terraform
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
        tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
        allow-no-subscriptions: true

    - name: Setup Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
 
    - name: Terraform Init
      run: terraform init

    - name: Terraform Apply
      run: terraform apply -auto-approve
```